# How to add Customer custom attributes and address custom attributes

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, address-attribute

I had many issues trying to add new customer account and address fields.
Sometimes it wasn't showing up on the customer adminhtml form and on other times won't save the value.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, figured it out.

Here is my working Setup/InstallData.php with some examples for text / checkbox / date fields:

```
namespace Vendor\CustomerModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $_eavSetupFactory;
    private $_attributeRepository;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeRepository $attributeRepository
    )
    {
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->_attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;

    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerSetupFac = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $setup->startSetup();

        $customerEntity = $customerSetupFac->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        //customer fields
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_number');
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_number', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'POS Customer Number',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1003,
            'position' => 1003,
            'system' => 0,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        ]);

        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'end_membership');
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'end_membership', [
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'label' => 'End Membership date',
            'input' => 'date',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 998,
            'position' => 998,
            'system' => 0,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        ]);

        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'allow_sms');
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'allow_sms', [
            'type' => "int",
            'label' => 'Allow SMS',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1004,
            'position' => 1004,
            'system' => 0,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        ]);


        //address fields
        $customerSetupFac->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Address\AttributeProvider::ENTITY, 'house_number');
        $customerSetupFac->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Address\AttributeProvider::ENTITY, 'house_number',  [
            'label' => 'House number',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'text',
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'source' => '',
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'group'=>'General',
            'visible_on_front' => 1,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
            'position' => 222,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $customerSetupFac->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Address\AttributeProvider::ENTITY, 'apartment_number');
        $customerSetupFac->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Address\AttributeProvider::ENTITY, 'apartment_number',  [
            'label' => 'Apartment number',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'text',
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'source' => '',
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'group'=>'General',
            'visible_on_front' => 1,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
            'position' => 222,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $customerSetupFac->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Address\AttributeProvider::ENTITY, 'mobile_number');
        $customerSetupFac->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Address\AttributeProvider::ENTITY, 'mobile_number',  [
            'label' => 'Mobile number',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'text',
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'source' => '',
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'group'=>'General',
            'visible_on_front' => 1,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
            'position' => 222,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);


        // allow attributes to be saved in the specific areas

        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";

        $customer_number = $customerSetupFac->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_number');
        $customer_number
            ->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("attribute_set_id", $attributeSetId)
            ->setData("attribute_group_id", $attributeGroupId)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 77);
        $customer_number->save();

        $end_membership = $customerSetupFac->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'end_membership');
        $end_membership
            ->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("attribute_set_id", $attributeSetId)
            ->setData("attribute_group_id", $attributeGroupId)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 91);
        $end_membership->save();

        $allow_sms = $customerSetupFac->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'allow_sms');
        $allow_sms
            ->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("attribute_set_id", $attributeSetId)
            ->setData("attribute_group_id", $attributeGroupId)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 95);
        $allow_sms->save();

        //address
        $house_number = $customerSetupFac->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'house_number');
        $house_number
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer_address',
                'customer_address_edit',
                'customer_register_address'
            ]]);
        $house_number->save();

        $apartment_number = $customerSetupFac->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'apartment_number');
        $apartment_number
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer_address',
                'customer_address_edit',
                'customer_register_address'
            ]]);
        $apartment_number->save();

        $mobile_number = $customerSetupFac->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'mobile_number');
        $mobile_number
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer_address',
                'customer_address_edit',
                'customer_register_address'
            ]]);
        $mobile_number->save();

        /**************    */

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```